# how to fix mysql access denied? works on home server but not on production server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-5

On my home server running rails 5.2.2 and ruby 2.6.1, everything works fine; but on my linode I get  Access denied for user 'deploy'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
In database.yml on home server, I use david as the user, which is the unix account. Using the same database.yml on the linode, I have deploy as the user in the database.yml file. deploy is the unix account for the linode server.

I've tried the root account and granted all to root and deploy, but neither works

...
mysql> show grants;
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for deploy@localhost                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'deploy'@'localhost'       |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mysql`.* TO 'deploy'@'localhost' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
...
...

database.yml on home server

```
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql_development
  pool: 5
  username: david
  password: "password"
  host: localhost
  port: 3306


test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql_test
  pool: 5
  username: david
  password: "password"
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

### ...

database.yml on linode server

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql_development
  pool: 5
  username: deploy
  password: "password"
  host: localhost
  port: 3306


test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql_test
  pool: 5
  username: deploy
  password: "password"
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mysql_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Wait, you have two different `database.yml` files?

As far as I see, you have `david@localhost` in one, and `deploy@localhost` in another one.

I don't see a reason to do that.

The whole purpose of database.yml file is to define the logins for localhost, staging, testing, etc. and production. In production you'd normally set it up using .env file, or using the encrypted credentials with Rails 5.2.

That way you're able to store your Linode server credentials in a safe place without sacrificing the functionality.

Here is an example of our own `database.yml` file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  reconnect: true
  host: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_HOST') {'127.0.0.1'} %>
  port: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_PORT') {'3306'} %>
  database: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_NAME') {'our_dev_server'} %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_USER') {'root'} %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch('DB_PASSWORD') { '' } %>
  variables:
    sql_mode: TRADITIONAL # Read more: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25924

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default
  database: our_test_server

production:
  <<: *default
```

Comment: The one on my development server at home is working.